# Load scene without building settings

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have a game with lobby scene and many levels and every level is a different scene, my game is for mobile and I wan't to upload my scenes to an s3 bucket on aws and download new scenes when I want without add the scenes to the build setting.
I make my scene an asset bundle and build it, but when I download the asset I can't load it because is not in my build settings, how can I do this?

Comment: Someone know how the solurtion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a long time I find a way to load scene with asset bundle **without** add the scenes to add the scenes to the build settings.
the issue seems to be a bug with the AssetBundle.LoadFromFile of unity.
this is why I use AssetBundle.LoadFromStream both when I load my scene the is saved locally and when I download my scene from my bucket on s3.

this is my code:

```
  bool isSaved = File.Exists(savingPath);
            AssetBundle mySceneLoadedAssetBundle = null;
            if (isSaved)
            {
                Debug.Log($"Use open asset budnle of {fileName}");
                using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead(savingPath))
                {
                    mySceneLoadedAssetBundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromStream(fileStream);

                    AsyncOperation asyncOperation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(fileName, LoadSceneMode.Single);
                    mySceneLoadedAssetBundle.Unload(false);

                    callback?.Invoke();
                    Debug.Log("finish load the scene");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (Stream fileStream = File.Create(savingPath))
                {

                    await (await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()).CopyToAsync(fileStream);

                    mySceneLoadedAssetBundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromStream(fileStream);

                    AsyncOperation asyncOperation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(fileName, LoadSceneMode.Single);
                    mySceneLoadedAssetBundle.Unload(false);
                    callback?.Invoke();
                    Debug.Log("finish load the scene");

                }
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use Unity Addressable package.

CodeMonkey has a video on how to use it.
(Link: [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C6i_JiRoIfk&t=968s&ab_channel=CodeMonkey))

Comment: I already work with asset bundles and no adressable and I don't want to use it because it's mean many changes on my project.

Comment: Unless your scenes get generated from instructions you havent really got a choice. So either generate them from instructions you define a format for. Or. Addressables.

Comment: what do you mean by instructions? @BugFinder

Comment: well that would be down to you to define, its your game

Comment: Do you mean to build all my game object inside my scene? I want to load my scene entire scene from asset bundle as it is and not to recreate the scene by myself.

Comment: I publish my solution, this solution don't exist on the web.